# How can i get array added as parameter when sending ajax post using "data"

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can i send this array as a parameter in ajax post ?

```
var abilitiesAR=['LINEUPS0001=on', 'WAIVERS0002=on', 'TRADES0002=on']
```

I want the url when posting to look like this

```
urlPath&LINEUPS0001=on&WAIVERS0002=on&TRADES0002=on
```

Here is my ajax post attempt , but I can't figure out any way to get the url parameters added how i need them to be, i have my efforts marked out

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseURLDynamic + '/' +year+'/owner_abilities_setup?LEAGUE_ID='+league_id+abilitiesAR,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    //data: JSON.stringify(abilitiesAR),
    //data: JSON.stringify({abilitiesAR}),
    //data: {abilitiesAR},
    //data: {'+abilitiesAR+'},
    //data: {'abilitiesAR[]':abilitiesAR},
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
            console.log(settings.url);
    }
});
```

Comment: 1) To be clear, you're making a GET request to get HTML from a server which lists all *checked* checkboxes, to then send that same information ***back to the same server*** in a POST request...? If the server already knows what data is checked in the first GET request, then the second request is entirely pointless. 2) POST requests should ideally send content in the request body, not the URL 3) `newURL` will only ever hold the single value it was set to in the last iteration of the loop. If you really want to do what you're attempting, push the values in to an array and sent that in the POST.

Comment: @Rory , #1 - yes , #3 corrected and put in array

Answer (score 0):

i had to join the array items , then when i do the ajax post it adds to end or url

```
var joinArray = abilitiesAR.join("&");

$.ajax({
    url: baseURLDynamic + '/' +year+'/owner_abilities_setup?LEAGUE_ID='+league_id,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    data: joinArray,
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
            console.log(settings.url);
    }
});
```